# Yii CException: Cannot Access Update Page

Tags: php, yii

[image: CException]

I've got this error while accessing the pembeli/update, although the update.php is in the folder views/pembeli/update.
What is this error means??
Thanks for answering

Comment: Check your controller and see what view you are rendering for that action.

Comment: Yii encountered an exception, but while it was trying to render that exception's details to the screen it encountered another exception (namely, that the `views/site/error.php` view used to render errors was not present and could not be rendered). That is the error you are seeing now. Create (restore) that view and reopen this page, either the error message or your application logs will tell you about the original exception.

Comment: do you mean this? public function actionView($id)
 {
  $this->render('view',array(
   'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
  ));
 }

I think it is right. But why still dont work

Comment: oh Isee DCoder. I removed the error.php out from views/site. I thought it was unnecessary. So I moved it back to views/site and it is work. Thanks a lot